# JS Calculator: Unobtrusive Alternative to onlick

Tags: javascript, calculator, unobtrusive-javascript

I have my current html setup with inline js. This includes a  that has inputs such as:

```
<input type="button" value="7" onclick="appendSymbol(value)" />
```

I've researched unobtrusive js and have even got as far as [object mouseclick] appearing in my results window when a button is clicked. I need an unobtrusive way to have the value entered into my appendSymbol function.

[Here](http://cs.mhu.edu/~s000178083/java/calculator%201/calculator1.html) is the calculator with obtrusive js.

I'm not looking for entire snippets, just advice or a point of reference.

Comment: Have a look at these articles to learn all there is to know about event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a click handler to run after the input is loaded.

If you're using a framework such as jquery, this becomes very easy:

```
$("input").click(function(e){
  appendSymbol($(this).val());
});
```

If you're not, you can do the same in plain javascript with:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() { ... }, false);
```